# Finding a function based on the value of extrema

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> **Question:**
>
> If $f(x)=a\ln |x|+bx^2+x$ has its extremum values at $x=-1$ and $x=2$, then find the values of $a$ and $b$.
>
> (A) $a=2,b=-1$
>
> (B) $a=2,b=-1/2$
>
> (C) $a=-2,b=1/2$
>
> (D) None of these

**My Approach:**

Since the derivative of a function becomes zero or vanishes at extremum points, I calculated the derivative of $f(x)$

$f'(x)=\frac a {|x|}+2bx+1$

Then I computed $f'(-1)$ and $f'(2)$ and equated them to zero, and obtained two linear equations in $a$ and $b$.

$a-2b+1=0$ and $a+8b+2=0$

Then I calculated the values of $a$ and $b$ to be $\frac{-6}{5}$ and $\frac{-1}{10}$ respectively.

So, I chose the option (D) but the correct option as given in my book is (B) and the solution as given in my book is as follows:

[image]

The main difference from my approach and the solution is the calculation of the derivative of $\ln |x|$. Of course, I know derivative of $\ln |x|$ is $1/|x|$, but here should we want to neglect that fact as in the book.

I want to know whether my approach is correct or not, and whether my book is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that derivative of $\ln |x|$ is $\frac 1 {|x|}$. When $x <0$ the derivative is $\frac 1 {-x} (-1)=\frac 1 x \neq \frac 1 {|x|}$. What the book says is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. If possible could you please help me [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379242/condition-on-the-discriminant-of-the-second-derivative-of-a-biquadratic-function) when you find time?

Comment: The comment there is accurate. Concave does not mean strictly concave. You have to include points with $f''(x)=0$. @Intellex

Comment: Thank you very much sir.